# How to render multiple AmCharts (version 3) Serial chart on same page?

Tags: amcharts

I need a page with several charts (render multiple aspects of same dataset).

- I use the same dataset
- with the same chartConfig (cloned by $.extend
- 2 charts
- all are serial type

Here is the problem code http://jsfiddle.net/mZ2Gq/227/

```
var chart1 = AmCharts.makeChart("chart1div", $.extend(true, AMCHART_SERIAL_CONFIG, { "theme": "dark" }) );
var chart2 = AmCharts.makeChart("chart2div", $.extend(true, AMCHART_SERIAL_CONFIG, { "theme": "light" }) );
```

It only can render the last chart propertly. How can I work-around this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you're using the same configuration object for both charts. This does not work.

You can solve this by using an empty object `{}` as target in the [`$.extend`](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.extend/) method.
Just like this:

```
AmCharts.makeChart("chart", $.extend(true, {}, AMCHART_SERIAL_CONFIG, {theme: "dark"}));
```

Here's your updated [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/b5h69Lx4/).

**Note:** You should avoid using deep merge if not necessary. It slows your code.

Comment: Oh yeah, my fault (misunderstanding $.extend, I thought it will **return new object**, instead of extend the **target**).
I use "deep merge" because the Amchart config extending task  will be  deep.

Thank you.